# ArcGIS Field Calculator returning error 000989?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, error-000989

I am trying to calculate a percentage of a field based off the value of another field.
if damage = x then return  the value of field !mrkt_imprv! * y

```
y = percentage value
```

my code is below its returning an error in the calculate field

```
def dam_cal():
    if !DAMAGE! == 'Affected':
        return !IMPRV_MRKT! * .1
    elif !DAMAGE! == 'Minor':
        return !IMPRV_MRKT! * .2
    elif !DAMAGE! == 'Major':
        return !IMPRV_MRKT! * .65
    elif !DAMAGE! == 'Destroyed':
        return !IMPRV_MARKT! * .85
```

the error is #000989 (line 2)
Parameters are not valid.

Comment: Does this answer help?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/119286/43

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within field calculator the field values need to be referened as a argument in the function, try this:

```
def dam_cal(damage, imprv_mrkt):
    if damage == 'Affected':
        return imprv_mrkt * .1
    elif damage == 'Minor':
        return imprv_mrkt * .2
    elif damage == 'Major':
        return imprv_mrkt * .65
    elif damage == 'Destroyed':
        return imprv_mrkt * .85
```

function call:

```
dam_cal(!DAMAGE!, !IMPRV_MARKT!)
```

You may also want to add additional logic to make sure impv_mrkt value is not NULL or 0 before multiplying it.