# How to work with accentuated strings in Python scripts in ArcGIS Desktop Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

`

```
pre-logic:
def myCalc(name,nameVal):
  if (name == nameVal):
    return 1
  else:
    return 0

var_name=
myCalc(!Epulettipus!,"Lakóépület")
```

`

This doesn't work with accentuated strings. (But works with unaccentuated strings). What can I do?

Comment: I hope [this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) helps.

Comment: @dassouki why would that help me? I don't see that. 
I hope is there some kind of library what can I use, for example "unidecode" in this script, but I could not find any example for doing that in field calculator.

Comment: This may help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/61598/115

Comment: Not really yet.

Comment: Not that the code you have is wrong, but you could shorten it by setting the return value at the start and in the if statement changing it as needed, then return the value. Saves an else and multiple returns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a `u` in front of the string so the interpreter knows it's Unicode.

```
myCalc(!Epulettipus!, u"Lakóépület")
```